# Is there a way to force postgresql to return repeatitive(duplicate) records for the repetitive ids in "IN" clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, where-in

The query goes like this

```
SELECT "students"."full_name" FROM "students" WHERE "students"."id" IN (1, 2, 3, 6, 785, 1, 2, 3, 785, 6)
```

Right now only 5 results are returned.

But I would like to get 10 results in a single query.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with an IN clause, but you can use a JOIN:

```
SELECT s.full_name 
FROM students s
  JOIN unnest(array[1, 2, 3, 6, 785, 1, 2, 3, 785, 6]) as x(id) on s.id = x.id;
```

A more standard compliant version would be a `values` clause

```
SELECT s.full_name 
FROM students s
  JOIN ( 
     values (1), (2), (3), (6), (785), (1), (2), (3), (785), (6)
  ) as x(id) on s.id = x.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "No", however, you can do something like that:

```
SELECT full_name
FROM "students" s 
INNER JOIN (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (6), (785), (1), (2), (3), (785), (6)) v (id)
ON s.id = v.id
```

The sort order will be undetermined though.